# Date & Time --> select specific calendar weeks

Tags: php, datetime

I have a function which gives me all calendar weeks from a specific year. I created a dropdown menu with all calendar weeks. My function looks likes this:

```
function listYearWeeks($year) {

        $weeks=array();
        $run_stamp=strtotime($year."-01-01");

        for ($x=0;$x<366;$x++) {
            if (date("w",$run_stamp)==0) { // Montag
                if ($weeks[date("W",$run_stamp)]=="") {
                    $weeks[date("W",$run_stamp)]=$run_stamp;
                }
            }
            $run_stamp=($run_stamp+86400);
        }

        return $weeks;

}
```

My html/php code looks likes this:

```
<?php $data=listYearWeeks(2018); ?>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3'>
        <select class='form-control' name='calendar' id='calendar' onChange='changeDate()'>
            <?php foreach ($data as $key=>$value) { ?>
                <option value='".$value."'>Calendar week <?php  ".$key." ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select><br />

    </div>
</div>
```

I do have a dropdown now with alle calendar weeks from the year 2018. What I need to achieve is, that not all calendar weeks are shown inside the select options, instead it should start from the current calendar week and should show always the next three calendar weeks.

So the select options should be:
Calendar week 23 (current calendar week)
Calendar week 24
Calendar week 25
Calendar week 26

Can someone tell me what I need to change to start with the current calendar week and only show the next 3 calendar weeks?

Answer (score 0):

It's a heavy thing for what you want.
First you can start from now, not from the begining of the year:
`$run_stamp=strtotime($year."-01-01");`  => `$run_stamp=time();`

But more efficient:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $week = date("W", strtotime("+$i weeks"));
    echo '<option value="' . $week . '">Calendar week ' . $week . '"</option>';
}
```

Note that, that way it will work even if you're in the last week of the year.